# Any reason why to use !! in c++?

Tags: c++

Recently, I came across following code snippet, I couldn't know the reason. Any one has any idea, why negate two times (and not just return the value of doAction())?
return !!doAction();

Comment: The rightmost ! is `bool operator!()` that returns a bool based on the object which is not a bool. The leftmost ! is a negation.

Comment: It could be conversion, if doAction returns an `int` (for example) then `!!doAction()` will have a `bool` value.

Comment: If you need such behavior as mentiond above, please implement `operator bool() const`

Comment: Hard to say for sure.  You've not included enough of the code snippet to ascertain the exact reason it's doing `!!doAction();`, but in general it's probably not necessary to do the `!!` part because C++ is pretty promiscuous about what it considers a booly truthy (anything not zero) and booly falsy (anything zero).

Comment: Thank you all. I think i've got the idea.